# How can I troubleshoot an AWS VPN connection that suddenly stopped working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-vpn

We have an AWS VPN Client Endpoint set up and are using OpenVPN as the client to connect. This has worked with no issues until today. I don't see any outages that are relevant and the error message we're getting is:

`Lost connection to server : 1 times`

The Client VPN endpoint is still showing as available in AWS:

[image]

Certs are valid until next year and the CA is valid until 10 years from now.

Nothing has changed that I know of since we were able to connect. What steps should I take to troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing I tried resolved the issue.  I recreated a client VPN endpoint with the same settings and it works fine.  I deleted the old one and notified everyone of the updated endpoint.  Weird.